Rav Yosef Engel’s 20 books on Kabbalah?
Rav Yosef Engel (Polish rabbi and halakhist, 1859–1920) is reputed to have written over 20 works on Kabbalah.
What were these 20 works, which are still available, and what is the uniqueness of each?

Not true sefarim.com selling otzerot Yosef in which they printed 3–better to be silent rather than inaccurate
